# WCF REST Webinvoke not found

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, .net-4.0, webinvoke

Following is the code i am using in my test app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.IO;

namespace MyWCFServices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        String GetMessage(String name);

        //[OperationContract]
        //[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",UriTemplate = "File/{fileName}")]
        //[WebContentType("application/octet-stream")]
        // bool UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents); 
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}")]
        void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContent); 
    }
}
```

It gives and error on compilation for webinvoke. Any idea about the same ??

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`WebInvokeAttribute` is in separate assembly System.ServiceModel.Web.dll. Did you reference that assembly? Also you must add `using System.ServiceModel.Web;`

Edit:

To use System.ServiceModel.Web.dll assembly you must use at least .NET 3.5 and you can't use .NET 4.0 Client Profile.

Comment: What version of .NET/WCF are you using?

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0 (not 4.0 Client Profile)

Comment: I have never heard about `WebContentType` attribute and as I know it is not part of WCF.

Comment: What type of project are you using?

Comment: @Ladislav : I'm facing the same issue. Also, I don't see reference to System.ServiceModel.Web in add reference dialog. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 (.net 4.0). Can you help me if i'm missing something ??

Comment: Hmmm...dont mind but what specific client profile are you asking? I'm new to web and working on creating a simple page in html5 and need to call a webservice.

Comment: list of namespace added:
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Runtime.Serialization;  using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

Comment: I am also facing same problem. i am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: somehow ReSharper isn't able to add the reference automatically

Comment: @Rohit what was the solution?